# Entity Framework executes unnecessary SQL queries while all the data is already fetched in memory?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
var logs = myContext.Logs.Where(x => ...).ToList();
var objectIds = logs.Select(x => x.ObjectId).Distinct().ToArray();
var objects = myContext.MyObjects.Where(x => objectIds.Contains(x.ID)).ToList();

foreach (MyObject myObject in objects)
{
    myObject.Logs = logs.Where(x => x.ObjectId == myObject.ID).ToList();
}
```

When I look at the generated queries, I have:

```
SELECT * FROM LOGS WHERE ...
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM MYOBJECTS WHERE ID IN (...)
```

That's what I want but I have an unnecessary query for each iteration after

```
SELECT * FROM LOGS WHERE OBJECTID = ...
```

I assumed from my first two queries that all data was loaded so why run new queries in database?

Comment: Too many queries in your code, why don't you try to combine all these in a single query using joins?

Comment: I simplified my code but in my first attempt I effectively had a single query with multiple `.Include()` and had terrible perf. I had to try by splitting in multiple queries, my goal was achieved except with this one to many relationship. Please only consider this

Comment: That certainly won't repro as is. `logs` is an in-memory List.  `logs.Where(…)` won't generate any queries.  You can sometimes get unexpected queries due to lazy loading, so you might turn that off in your next attempt at a repro.

Answer (score 1):

When Entity Framework loads tracked objects, it adds them to the local repository which can be accessed via `context.Table.Local`. Running queries outside of the local repo will always translate to SQL and will be run on the database engine. This being said, I do think a combined query with joins is more appropriate in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

How, without assuming it is the ONLY instance ever working on it, is EF supposed to know that ALL data is loaded into memory nad no additional data has been created in the database?

That is the core problem. EF is not making assumptions on that, which is why it is making another query. There is time in between.